# QueryDSL com classe abstract

Tags: java, postgresql, querydsl

Preciso fazer uma query que retorne um objeto abstract. No caso quando meu código chega no ".list()" ele lança uma exception, por outro lado, se utilizo o ".list" mas retornando um atributo deste objeto ele funciona.

Só gostaria de saber se a queryDSL não consegue retornar um objeto abstract

```java
public List<DadoLidoGraficoDTO> buscarDadosDosGraficosGerenciais(List<Long> estacoes, Date dataInicio, Date dataFim, Integer tipoDado) {
    QDadoLidoEstacao entidade = QDadoLidoEstacao.dadoLidoEstacao;
    QLeituraEstacao entidadeLeitura = QLeituraEstacao.leituraEstacao;

    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

    List<DadoLidoGraficoDTO> resultado = query.from(entidade)
         .innerJoin(entidade.leituraestacao, entidadeLeitura)
         .where(entidadeLeitura.coletorDados.id.in(estacoes).and(entidade.dataHora.between(dataInicio, dataFim).and(entidade.tipoDado.identificadorTipo.eq(tipoDado))))
         .groupBy(entidadeLeitura.coletorDados.id, entidade.dataHora.month(), entidade.dataHora.dayOfMonth(), entidade.dataHora)
         .orderBy(entidade.dataHora.asc())
         .list(new QDadoLidoGraficoDTO(entidadeLeitura.coletorDados, entidade.valor.sum(), entidade.dataHora));

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o seu código para ver se a questão fica um pouco mais clara?

Answer (score 2):

Bom, assumindo que `QDadoLidoGraficoDTO`:

- é uma classe concreta
- herda da superclasse `DadoLidoGraficoDTO` (seja ela abstrata ou não)
- possui um construtor com três parâmetros (compatíveis com os argumentos sendo passados) devidamente anotado com `@QueryProjection` ([Documentação de Referência - Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.0/reference/html/ch03s02.html#d0e1913))

Seu problema está mais embaixo:

Tipos genéricos em Java são **invariantes**, ou seja `List<QDadoLidoGraficoDTO>` não é um subtipo de `List<DadoLidoGraficoDTO>` ([The Java™ Tutorials - Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)).

O que significa que em Java essa não é uma atribuição válida:

```
List<DadoLidoGraficoDTO> l1 = // ...
List<QDadoLidoGraficoDTO> l2 = // ...
l1 = l2; // inválido - não compila
```

Porém você pode usar um *wildcard* para dizer que `DadoLidoGraficoDTO` é um limite superior do tipo esperado ([The Java™ Tutorials - Wildcards and Subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)):

```
List<? extends DadoLidoGraficoDTO> l1 = // ...
List<QDadoLidoGraficoDTO> l2 = // ...
l1 = l2; // ok QDadoLidoGraficoDTO é um subtipo de DadoLidoGraficoDTO
```

Logo, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
List<? extends DadoLidoGraficoDTO> resultado = query.from(entidade)
     .innerJoin(entidade.leituraestacao, entidadeLeitura)
     .where(entidadeLeitura.coletorDados.id.in(estacoes).and(entidade.dataHora.between(dataInicio, dataFim).and(entidade.tipoDado.identificadorTipo.eq(tipoDado))))
     .groupBy(entidadeLeitura.coletorDados.id, entidade.dataHora.month(), entidade.dataHora.dayOfMonth(), entidade.dataHora)
     .orderBy(entidade.dataHora.asc())
     .list(new QDadoLidoGraficoDTO(entidadeLeitura.coletorDados, entidade.valor.sum(), entidade.dataHora));
```